# simple regular expression with equals but dont want to use split

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the message string as follows.

```
string=052
```

I need to use regular expression not split.

I want to return everything past the equals. 052
This is what i tried and gives me id=null

```
var regex = '[^?string=]';
var id2 = mystring.match(regex);
```

I have tried online regex checkers and it looks like it matches all but the a

is there a better reg ex i should try? id should not equal null.

Comment: Use `substring`/`substr` and `indexOf`.

Comment: Just split by `=` and get the 1st element in array

Comment: You could perform a split on `=` or just do `message=[a-z0-9]+`

Comment: @MikeC `message=([a-z0-9]+)`

Comment: @Enissay Oops, forgot the parentheses. You're right.

Comment: I asked for regular expression not split. Split is not what i asked for. Please take it off duplicate.

Comment: This is a poor flagging, @WiktorStribiżew . It does not pertain to the OPs question directly. Expecting them to suss it out defeats the purpose of coming to SO for quick, distilled information. Either link to a better answer, or remove the flag. The OP specifically mentions not using split after an edit. Please remove this specific flagging and update appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) incorrectly. Try this:

```
var regex = '^message=(.*)$';
var id = queryString.match(regex)[1];
```

`.match()` returns an array; the first element (at `[0]`) is the entire matched string, and the second element (at `[1]`) is the part that's matched in the (first) set of parentheses in the regex.

Comment: works as needed. Thank you